# Unreliable nested while loops?

Tags: python, while-loop, logic

Im having a logic confusion here and don't know whether a solution is possible with my setup.

I am trying to prompt the user for (in order)

1. user answer y/n (originally set to 'y')
2. a bet (based on their current money)
3. a guess on a number 1-6.

Until the user answers anything but `y`, I will loop this program.
At stage 2, I will loop asking for a bet if the bet is invalid/not in range of their current money.
At stage 3, I will loop asking for a guess if the guess is not 1-6 or invalid.

My code below works, if the user answers with a valid guess all the time:

```
def roll():
    return [random.randrange(1,6), random.randrange(1,6), random.randrange(1,6)]

# Returns positive [betamount] or negative [betamount] depending on if guess is in diceroll list
def computeBetResult(diceRolls, betAmount, guessed):
    return (int(betAmount) if (int(guessed) in diceRolls) else -1*int(betAmount)) if (int(betAmount) > 0) else 0

# PART 2 - prompt user input and continually ask for new bets and guesses, until user says to quit
def main():
    money = 100
    userAnswer = 'y'
    print('Welcome to Gambling.')
    while(userAnswer.strip().lower() == 'y'):
        bet = input('You have $' + str(money) + '. How much would you like to bet?')
        while(bet.strip().isnumeric() and int(bet) > 0 and int(bet) <= money):
            guess = input('What number are you betting on? (number 1-6)')
            while (int(guess) >= 1 and int(guess) <= 6):
                print("Ok. You bet $" + str(bet).strip() + ' on the number ' + str(guess))
                # Actually calculate the roll
                theRoll = roll()
                print('You rolled: ' + str(theRoll[0]) + ', ' + str(theRoll[1]) + ', ' + str(theRoll[2]))
                if (int(computeBetResult(theRoll, bet, guess)) > 0):
                    print('You won your bet!')
                    money += int(bet)
                else:
                    print('You lost your bet :(')
                    money -= int(bet)
                print('You now have $' + str(money).strip())
                # Prompt again
                userAnswer = input('Would you like to play again (y/n)?')
                break
            break
```

But if I get through with a valid bet, but not a valid guess, the program will just move on back to the top of the outermost while loop and ask for a bet again (from console):

```
You have $100. How much would you like to bet?0
You have $100. How much would you like to bet?0
You have $100. How much would you like to bet?100
What number are you betting on? (number 1-6)0
You have $100. How much would you like to bet?
```

I've tried

```
if (int(guess) < 1 or int(guess) > 6):
            guess = input('What number are you betting on? (number 1-6)')
```

at the very end of the outer while loop, but this then results in guess being asked for unnecessarily.

Is my setup all wrong or how can I fix this?

Updated attempt:

```
def main():
    money = 100
    userAnswer = 'y'
    print('Welcome to Gambling.')
    while(userAnswer.strip().lower() == 'y'):
        bet = input('You have $' + str(money) + '. How much would you like to bet?')
        while(bet.strip().isnumeric() and int(bet) > 0 and int(bet) <= money):
            guess = input('What number are you betting on? (number 1-6)')
            while (int(guess) >= 1 and int(guess) <= 6):
                print("Ok. You bet $" + str(bet).strip() + ' on the number ' + str(guess))
                # Actually calculate the roll
                theRoll = roll()
                print('You rolled: ' + str(theRoll[0]) + ', ' + str(theRoll[1]) + ', ' + str(theRoll[2]))
                if (int(computeBetResult(theRoll, bet, guess)) > 0):
                    print('You won your bet!')
                    money += int(bet)
                else:
                    print('You lost your bet :(')
                    money -= int(bet)
                print('You now have $' + str(money).strip())
                # Prompt again
                userAnswer = input('Would you like to play again (y/n)?')
                break
        if(userAnswer.strip().lower() != 'y'):
            break
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too broad.

Comment: Its because you have a break as the last line in the code snippet. If the input is not between 1 and 6 it breaks out of the middle while loop. You need to change your logic there

Comment: The problem is your second `break` - the one in the last line. It is executed every time after the innermost loop, and exits the middle loop, returning you to the beginning of the outermost loop.

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: @Błotosmętek Alright, took out the break but now still having issues.. check my edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright - this was the right way to do it:

```
money = 100
    userAnswer = 'y'
    print('Welcome to Gambling.')
    while userAnswer.strip().lower() == 'y':
        while True:
            bet = int(input('You have $' + str(money) + '. How much would you like to bet?'))
            if bet <=0 or bet > money:
                print('Invalid bet - bet must be greater than 0 and less than '+str(money))
                continue
            # Valid bet entered
            break
        while True:
            guess = int(input('What number are you betting on? (number 1-6)'))
            if guess < 1 or guess > 6:
                print('Invalid guess - you must enter a value 1-6')
                continue
            # Valid guess entered
            break
        print("Ok. You bet $" + str(bet).strip() + ' on the number ' + str(guess))
        # Actually calculate the roll
        theRoll = roll()
        print('You rolled: ' + str(theRoll[0]) + ', ' + str(theRoll[1]) + ', ' + str(theRoll[2]))
        if (int(computeBetResult(theRoll, bet, guess)) > 0):
            print('You won your bet!')
        else:
            print('You lost your bet :(')
        money += int(computeBetResult(theRoll, bet, guess))
        userAnswer = input('Would you like to play again (y/n)?')
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the while condition in the loop that asks for a valued number and put it inside the actual loop, so that when it is an invalid number, it asks for another one.

Edited while condition because of @AMC 's comment

Edited to put the whole code that solves the problem:

```
def main():
    money = 100
    userAnswer = 'y'
    print('Welcome to Gambling.')
    while(userAnswer.strip().lower() == 'y'):
        bet = input('You have $' + str(money) + '. How much would you like to bet?')
        while(bet.strip().isnumeric() and int(bet) > 0 and int(bet) <= money):
            guess = input('What number are you betting on? (number 1-6)')
            while true:
                if int(guess) < 1 or int(guess > 6):
                    guess = input("Please choose a valid number") #will keep asking for a valid number if it is wrong
                    continue
                else:
                    print("Ok. You bet $" + str(bet).strip() + ' on the number ' + str(guess))
                    # Actually calculate the roll
                    theRoll = roll()
                    print('You rolled: ' + str(theRoll[0]) + ', ' + str(theRoll[1]) + ', ' + str(theRoll[2]))
                    if (int(computeBetResult(theRoll, bet, guess)) > 0):
                        print('You won your bet!')
                        money += int(bet)
                    else:
                        print('You lost your bet :(')
                        money -= int(bet)
                        print('You now have $' + str(money).strip())
                    # Prompt again
                    userAnswer = input('Would you like to play again (y/n)?')
                    if userAnswer=="n":
                        break
```

Comment: Why use `while (1):` instead of  `while True:`, since you're just relying on the fact that 1 is truthy? You don't need all the parentheses in the if statements by the way, and variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores style`. This isn't Java ;)

Comment: This doesn't work - it doesnt prompt initially for the bet value and doesn't re-prompt if they dont answer a valid bet.

Comment: I'm editing the answer since I forgot to specificate that this loop should replace the while loop after the line `guess = input('What number are you betting on? (number 1-6)')`. I will put the whole answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

From a quick glance your problem seems to lie in the fact that when you enter an invalid guessing number, you never enter the third and final loop.

```
guess = input('What number are you betting on? (number 1-6)')
while (int(guess) >= 1 and int(guess) <= 6):
```

If you enter in a number that is `< 1` or `> 6` then you will never enter the while loop and directly jump to the `break` that is in the end of the second while loop which sends you back to the very first loop and asks you how much you want to bet again.

Try removing the `break` in the second while loop and see what happens, the logic is currently not what you are looking for.

Comment: Alright, took out the break but now still having issues.. check my edit